# Both queue managers shows status as Running Else Where

Tags: ibm-mq

ByIn MQ HA server (multi-instance) both the queue managers shows the status us Running Else where.
Unable to stop or start the queue manager.
No queue manager logs or error logs are getting created.
MQ file system seems to be good.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that you have the latest fixpack installed to be sure you have fix for [APAR IV50422](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV50422) which reports a multi-instance queue manager as running elsewhere when it is not.

Please also confirm the shared file system you are using meets the [requirements.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21433474)

The way that the MQ multi-instance  feature works is as follows:

One qmgr is started on one node. Another qmgr is started on another 
node. Both qmgrs access the same qmgr data. Both try to get the lock on 
the same "master" file. The successful qmgr regards itself as the active
qmgr, writes identification information into the "master" file, and 
holds onto the lock. It commences full running as the active qmgr.

The unsuccessful qmgr regards itself as the standby qmgr and simply 
retries trying to obtain the lock on "master".

The active qmgr "monitors" the "master" file, reading it every 10s to 
check that the information it wrote into it when it became the active 
qmgr is unchanged.

If the active qmgr ends for whatever reason, the lock on "master" is 
dropped and the standby qmgr then gains the lock and becomes the active 
qmgr, writing its info into "master" and starting up full running.

It seems to me your problem may be with the lock on the master file. 
The switching between active and standby queue managers is governed by 
locks on files ("active", "master" and "standby") in the queue manager 
data directory.

In WebSphere MQ the following files are created by the queue manager /var/mqm/qmgrs/*QMGR*/active    /var/mqm/qmgrs/*QMGR*/master These files contain status information. 
Please check to see if these files are locked and if you are unable to 
release the file lock.

There are 4 files that come into play to determine what mode and status 
multi-instance qmgrs are in: 
amqmfsck.lck, active, standby, master.  These files are used by various 
mq process to determine status and functions of the qmgrs.  Check the status of those files,  as they may falsely be indicating qmgr as running when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

'Running Else where' means probably QMGR is down due to some reason and the lock is not released yet on 'master' and 'active' files. Move those files to some other name and start QMGR with command 'strmqm -x QMGR_NAME'. Refer previous answer to understand the usage of these files in IBM MQ multi-instance QMGR set up.